# tfjs, [1, 0, 0] prints as [true, false false]

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I know theres a method that prevents this but I can't seem to find it anymore. Does anyone know how to stop

tf.([1, 0, 0]).print() from resulting in [true, false, false]?

Answer (score 0):

`tf.tensor([1, 0, 0], null, 'bool').print()` is not a valid expression.

And unless a boolean dtype is specified, the default dtype is float and it will not print boolean

```js
tf.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4]).print(); // prints [1, 0, 0]
tf.tensor([1, 0, 0], null, 'bool').print() // prints  [true, false, false]
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm on tfjs, the javascript version doesn't require dtypes

Comment: I updated my code to show that it is using tfjs. The dtype is an optional parameter which defaults to `float`